# No visible @interface error in Xcode when building archive scheme (removing armv7 'solves' this)

Tags: ios, xcode

Specifically for the following method:

```
[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation
```

Everything works fine in debug (both simulator and device), but as soon as I want to build a release version, I get the following error:

```
No visible @interface for 'MKPinAnnotationView' declares the selector 'initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:'
```

The 'funny' thing is, I built an archive last week and this line looked exactly the same back then.

I've tried cleaning (build folder as well), deleting the derived data folder and restarting, but nothing helps.

I later found out that the error comes from 'armv7'. Removing this lets me build an archive, but with the warning that I should include 'armv7'.

So it's either Xcode or some build setting? Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was resolved when deleting ONLY the "ModuleCache" folder INSIDE the "Derived data" folder. For future reference.